# How to override mute/silent and vibrate for high priority notifications in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When the notification is received, no matter in what state the device is, it should ring.
like if the device is in a normal working state, it sounds for the notification
if the device is in DND mode, it should bypass DND and make the sound for the notification
if the device is in silent mode the notification should override the silent state and make a sound for the notification
Similarly, if the device is in vibrate mode it should override system settings snd make the sound for the notification

I am using the following code,

```
            val existingChannel =
                notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id)

            if (existingChannel != null) {
                notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id)
            }
            val mAudioManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(
                AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                50,
                0
            )

            val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)

            channel.description = description
            channel.enableLights(true)
            channel.setShowBadge(true)
            channel.describeContents()
            channel.setBypassDnd(dnd)
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            channel.lightColor = R.color.red
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.setSound(
                path,
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build()
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
```

But still, On silent, it won't sound for notifications.

Comment: Simply put, you shouldn't bypass DND - if it's on, it's on for a reason. If you require an alert, even in DND mode, ask for the user's permission to do this first, and only if they say yes, get your app to trigger an Alarm instead. If an app did this on my device in the middle of a meeting, it would be instantly uninstalled.

Comment: thats very NOT user friendly to make some sound when it silenced device, I would be very angry on an app, which make sound during my wedding or on some very important meeting. I doubt Android OS would allow you to override this in some easy way (not a workaround like manual playing ALARM sound instead of notification one)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an own notification channel for such a notification and ask the user to "ignore do not disturbe" in the notification settings on this channel for your app.